# Incrementar un precio con metodos - Java

Tags: java, porcentaje

soy nuevo en Java. Me dejaron un ejercicio que dice asi: **Crear un metodo** **incrementarPrecio:** que recibe como parametro un porcentaje de incremento de tipo entero, no tiene retorno.Calcula el porcentaje de incremento y le suma al precio actual. Hacer lo mismo con **decrementoPrecio** pero al contrario.

Sin embargo, auqneu no tenga eerrores, el resultado no es el que espero ya que ni suma y la resta no es acorde al porcentaje que se le pasa. Gracias por la ayuda.

**CLAS PRODUCTO**

```
package com.clearminds.componentes;

public class Producto {
    private String nombre;
    private String codigo;
    private double precio;

 // METODOS
public void incrementarPrecio(int incremento){
    precio = precio + ((incremento/100) * incremento);
}

public void disminuirPrecio(double disminuir){
    precio = precio - ((disminuir/100) * disminuir);
}

//CONSTRUCTOR
public Producto(String codigo,String nombre , double precio) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

//SET Y GETTERS

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public double getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public void setPrecio(double precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}

public String getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}
```

}

**CLASE TESTPRODUCTO**

```
package com.clearminds.test;

import com.clearminds.componentes.Producto;
public class TestProducto {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Producto producto=new Producto("KE34","Papitas",0.85);
    System.out.println("Código:"+producto.getCodigo());
    System.out.println("Nombre:"+producto.getNombre());
    System.out.println("Precio:"+producto.getPrecio());
    System.out.println("*************************************");
    producto.setPrecio(0.90);
    System.out.println("Nuevo Precio:"+producto.getPrecio());
    
    producto.incrementarPrecio(50);
    System.out.println("Precio incrementado:"+producto.getPrecio());
    // ME SALE: PRECIO INCREMENTADO : 0.90
    producto.disminuirPrecio(0.35);
    System.out.println("Precio incrementado:"+producto.getPrecio());
    // ME SALE : Precio incrementado:0.898775
    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esta mal tu fórmula obtener el precio incrementado y disminuido.

```
precio = precio + ((incremento/100) * incremento);
precio = precio - ((disminuir/100) * disminuir);
```

La fórmula es la siguiente.

```
precio = precio + ((incremento/100) * precio);
precio = precio - ((disminuir/100) * precio);
```

Ahora en tu descripción mencionas que tienes que crear 2 métodos para incrementar y disminuir el precio que reciban por parámetro un número entero con el incremento y decremento, pero que en tu método para disminuir precio, pasas un valor de tipo double lo cual contradice a lo que quieres realizar

```
public void disminuirPrecio(double disminuir){ //cambia el double por int
    precio = precio - ((disminuir/100) * disminuir);
}
```

Por último, cuando divides 2 números enteros el resultado será un número entero y cuando en numerador es menor que el denominador el resultado será 0. Ejemplo

```
int a=4;
int b=5;
System.out.println(a/b);
//La salida será 0
```

Si queremos que nos muestre el resultado en decimales tenemos que hacer un `cast` ya sea al numerador o denominador

```
int a=4;
int b=5;
System.out.println((double)a/b);
//La salida será 0.8
```

Por lo tanto los métodos de incremento y decremento quedarían de la siguiente forma:

```
public void incrementarPrecio(int incremento){
        this.precio = precio + ((double)incremento/100 * precio);
}

public void disminuirPrecio(int disminuir){
        this.precio = precio - ((double)disminuir/100* precio);
}
```

Comment: Hola gracias, me aclaraste lo de la formula ,vaya despiste mio. El metodo de incrementar funciono, pero el de disminuir sigo sin entender ya que en el ejercicio me dice asi:                                                                                      "Recibe un valor de descuento de tipo double, no retorna nada. Resta el valor de descuento al precio actual." . Por lo cual tendria que simplemente usar el valor de incrementarPrecio y restarlo al precio? De igual manera ya te di la respusta correcta porque me ayudaste un monton!

Comment: Ya entendi, solamente reste el saldo con el parametro que pasan y ya me dio el resultado que piden en el ejercicio xD . Mucahs gracias

Comment: Dale amigo, éxitos